# Nilradical of a Noetherian Ring is intersection of finitely many primes

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove that the nilradical of a Noetherian ring is the intersection of finitely many prime ideals but can not seem to do it.

I am trying to make a standard argument assuming, for contradiction, that the nilradical is not the intersection of finitely many prime ideals and deriving a contradiction but can't find one, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: which definition are you taking for the nilradical. Do you know it's the intersection of all prime ideals?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to somehow use that. Also, I know how to prove this result using Spec(R) and irreducible components but wanted to prove it using more basic properties of Noetherian rings.

Comment: Take the primary decomposition of the nilradical. Show that the primary decomposition of radical ideal consists of primes. The finiteness follows from Noether's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The nilradical is the intersection of all *minimal* prime ideals. So prove a noetherian ring has only a finite number of  minimal primes.

Comment: That is what I was eventually trying to prove by proving that the nilradical is the intersection of finitely many primes.